# evaluation of this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum\limits_{j=i}^{n} j = i + (i+1) + (i+2) + \cdots + (i+k)$$ note: above $(i+k) = n$ $$\\$$  now $$\sum\limits_{j=i}^{n} j = i \cdot(k+1) + \frac{(k+1)k}{2} = \frac{(k+1)(2i+k)}{2} $$ so my question is where does the $i \cdot (k+1)$ come from?? Also,  $$\frac{(k+1)(2i+k)}{2} = \frac{(n-i+1)(2i+n-i)}{2} = \frac{(n-i+1)(n+i)}{2}$$ How does the $$\frac{(k+1)(2i+k)}{2} = \frac{(n-i+1)(2i+n-i)}{2} ??$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is that each of the $k+1$ terms in your summation contain an $i$, so we can pull those out to get:
$$
i + (i+1) + (i + 2) + \dots + (i + k) = (i + i + \dots + i) + (1 + 2 + \dots + k)
$$
The first summation is just $i$, repeated $k+1$ times. The second summation is given by $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. For your second question, this is just the substitution $k = n-i$.

Alternatively, we could rewrite the sum as the following:
$$
\sum_{j=i}^n j = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - i} (i + j) = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - i} i + \sum_{j = 0}^{n - i} j = i(n - i + 1) + \frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}
$$
Note that this directly gives you the final answer.

Comment: how come you can rewrite $$\sum\limits_{j=i}^{n} j = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-i} (i+j) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-i} i + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-i} j$$ why does it work? was there a formula you used here?

Comment: I’m shifting the indices. It might be more clear to see if you rewrite the second sum to have an index variable of $k$ and set $j = i+k$.

Comment: what i see is 1 sum changed into two. I don't think the name of the index variable is an issue. Anyway, im even more confused now. Please try to show shifting indices clearly

Comment: The change from one sum into two is just splitting up each term of the sum.

Comment: but j=i was changed to j=0. n changed to n-i. j now appears to have changed to (i+j). You haven't said how any of those changes happened

Comment: Yes; you also have to adjust the term inside the summation, but that’s the idea

Comment: Ohh ok I get what you mean. Because if j = i+k we can use k index variable and get when j=i k=0 and when j=n k= n-i with the sum argument j equal to i + k can see the substitution. Always find people on here don’t like to provide specific details

Answer (score 0):

$(k+1)i$ comes from

$i+0+i+i+i+...i$ which contains 
$(k+1)$ terms.
Your sum is the difference

$$\sum_{j=1}^{i+k}j-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j=$$

$$\frac{(i+k)(i+k+1)}{2}-\frac{i(i-1)}{2}=$$

$$\frac{k(k+2i+1)+2i}{2}=i(k+1)+\frac{k(k+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Interesting, thank u!!